# How to serialize an enum with JSON.NET based on an attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Code below generates output as `{"error_message":null,"status":"InvalidRequest"}` where I would like to get it as `{"error_message":null,"status":"INVALID_REQUEST"}`

So simply, I was wondering how to honor `PropertyName` attribute while serializing with JSON.NET?

```
void Main()
{
    var payload = new GooglePlacesPayload();
    payload.Status = StatusCode.InvalidRequest;
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload).Dump();
}

public class GooglePlacesPayload
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "error_message")]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public StatusCode Status { get; set; }
}

[Flags]
public enum StatusCode
{
    // reference https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits#limitexceeded
    // reference https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchStatusCodes

    None = 0,

    // indicates that no errors occurred; the place was successfully detected and at least one result was returned.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "OK")]
    Ok = 1,
    // indicates that the search was successful but returned no results. This may occur if the search was passed a latlng in a remote location.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ZERO_RESULTS")]
    ZeroResults = 2,
    // indicates that you are over your quota.  The daily quotas are reset at midnight, Pacific Time.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT")]
    OverQueryLimit = 4,
    // indicates that your request was denied, generally because of lack of an invalid key parameter.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "REQUEST_DENIED")]
    RequestDenied = 8,
    // generally indicates that a required query parameter (location or radius) is missing.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "INVALID_REQUEST")]
    InvalidRequest = 16,

    // When the Google Places service returns a status code other than OK, there may be an additional error_message field within the search response object. 
    // This field contains more detailed information about the reasons behind the given status code.
    Positive = Ok | ZeroResults,
    Negative = OverQueryLimit | RequestDenied | InvalidRequest

}
```

Comment: I made the assumption that you are looking for *any* way to change the serialization of an enum.  If you're specifically looking for a way to use `PropertyName`, feel free to revert and add an update to your question to that effect.

Comment: You assumption was correct.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[EnumMember(Value="INVALID_REQUEST")]` should do it.  Note this is a dotnet core attribute, not newtonsoft-specific, so it *may* affect other things as well.

Comment: Luckily I'm on [tag:dotnet-core]   It looks like as long as you add `System.Runtime.Serialization` it works on both world by the way.    Thank you! 

Comment: @cilerler Heh, I meant "a core attribute of dotnet", not "an attribute of dotnet-core". Naming things....